# What are the invalid folder characters on OSX, Windows and Unix?

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I am using user's contents as a basis for folder name that I create on dropbox via their API.  What are the characters that would make folder names invalid on OSX, Windows and Unix? I would like to filter them out before creating the folder.

Comment: You cannot use the `/` or `'\0'` characters in a file name (or directory name) on Linux. Everything else is fine.

Comment: no reason to allow all possible, just allow all reasonable: alphanumeric plus some standards like - + _

Answer (score 0):

a file/folder name cannot contain any of the following characters on windows `/ \ : * < > |`
only have windows so dont know about osx and unix :(

Comment: Wow, the list is actually a lot longer than that: Byte values 0-31 are forbidden, and `con`, `prn`, `aux`, `nul,` etc. are all still against the rules: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: hmm didnt knew that.. i just wrote what windows itself told me. http://twitpic.com/5kjkzj